# My NodeJS server is not working in remove server

Tags: node.js, npm, server, next.js

When I run my NodeJS server in remote server with script "next" for example, it compiles successful and get "Running in localhost:3000" but when I try to enter to ip:3000 didn't get response from server.
What I should do?

Ubuntu server.

The server respond correctly without :3000

Comment: What is that “next” script exactly?

Comment: Where do you enter your ip:3000 to ? If you write localhost:3000 in your browser for example you should get a response. But its very hard to help with such limited information. Are you even logging your responses ?

Comment: Yes, in my browser.

Comment: It works like webpack-dev-server

Comment: Can you confirm the the remote server is reachable?

Comment: Without :3000 it works properly

Comment: Is the 3000 port open on the remote server, like if you are using AWS EC2 then you need to enable that port in security groups.

Comment: And what should your server do ? And how do you know it isn't responding ? Does it crash ? Are there no error messages ?
Try to figure out what is wrong and then please reform your question.

Comment: I run `ufw allow 3000` on my server (ubuntu server)

Comment: It didn't respond in my browser, 
Unable to access this website  has taken too long to respond.

Comment: did you try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54618507/my-nodejs-server-dont-work-in-remove-server/54618692#54618692

Comment: Solved, look my answer, thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to open the ports on your server for port 3000? :)

I'm on Ubuntu so this may be different on your system, but i think this should work for you.

```
ufw allow 3000
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling to find the issue with my remote server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access remotely you cannot listen your server using localhost

Try to listen server in `0.0.0.0`

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');

}).listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: Should I run my nodejs server with that configuration no?

Comment: you have to change your code with `.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");`

Comment: Just specifying port while calling the listen function will also work.

Comment: Are you using express.js

Answer (score 0):

Debugging this might follow a path on these lines:

- Verify the server is actually running on that machine. Try to connect to it locally from another shell on that that remote/server machine (use curl if the machine is headless). If it's not running locally, you clearly won't be able to connect remotely.
- Assuming the service is actually running, determine if you have the right IP address for the remote machine. Running something like ifconfig (ipconfig on windows I think?) will tell you this.
- Determine if you can reach the machine at all over the network. You might try to send it a ping, or connect to another service you know it's offering. If you can't reach it, is it running a firewall that's preventing you or is there address translation going on somewhere?

Comment: All works fine without port 3000 the problem is with that port.

Comment: Isn't there an error message? I will re-iterate my first and third comments. Does it *run* on port 3000, or not? (and if not, what's the output when you try to start it?) If it runs, can you reach it locally on port 3000 (that is, on the server)? If you can reach it from the server, but not from other machines, check firewalls (and routing, though your implication that you can connect remotely on other ports suggests routing is good).

Comment: Most likely, if it simply doesn't start on port 3000, is that port is already in use on that server (possibly an earlier attempt at running your software that didn't shutdown).